# After copying and inserting a row, is there a way to merge the values in select columns?

Tags: excel, vba

It has been a while since I have used VBA and I am just getting back into it, but I am wondering if is there a way, after you copy and insert a row, to only merge certain columns between the previous row and the new row? ie. only merge columns, A, B, C, etc.

The answer is probably not complicated but I cant seem to find the right method that doesn't involve calling a specific range (since it can be anything depending on selection). Thank you in advance!

The code I am using uses the selected row as follows:

```vb
Sub InsertCopyRow1()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```